# Convert procedure to UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to convert this procedure into UDF any suggestion. i have tried alot of things but can't access the required result

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLocationforSMS]  
@latt varchar(150)=null,
@lont varchar(150)
 AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml
CREATE TABLE #xml ( yourXML XML )

DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @QS varchar(50)
SELECT @QS = '&date='+convert(varchar(25),getdate(),126)
SELECT @URL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?
latlng='+@latt+','+@lont+'&sensor=false'  + @QS

 DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
 DECLARE @XML xml
 DECLARE @Obj int 
 DECLARE @Result int 
 DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
 DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)
 EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT
 EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
 EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 
INSERT #xml ( yourXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 
SELECT  yourXML.value('(//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') from #xml
```

Comment: Does your webservice have some kind of usage limitations ? Like anti-flood security or maybe number of use limited ?

Comment: Does your webservice behave the same if you query it with something else than SQL ? Like a SoapUI for example ?

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with [sql], your webservice simply does not behave as you wish. You have control on the webservice's code ?

Comment: "i want to convert this procedure into UDF any suggestion" - My suggestion is don't!

Comment: @MitchWheat dear i want to read xml and use required result in trigger any other way